# Markers on Google Maps API are not showing up with Geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places

I am trying to have places come up on the map based on the users geolocation. I know the geolocation works and map shows up, but none of the markers come up showing the local businesses. I am not getting any errors in console as well. I made sure that the script in my html is passing both the library and the API key, but just in case, here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MY_KEY"></script>
```

Here is my JavaScript...

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var service;

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    // Start Geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Found You!'
            });

            var request = {
                location: pos,
                radius: 500,
                types: ['store']
            };

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

            map.setCenter(pos);

        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

// Callback for Places
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Create Marker for Places
function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}

// Google Maps Error Flags

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}
```

Comment: maybe there is no store listed  500 meters around your location(for me your code works)

Comment: I increased the radius to 32186.9 (20 miles) and it still isn't working. I also added more types... types: ['dentist|store|restaurant'] any thoughts on what could be causing this? I am pretty sure my code is correct too.

Comment: and you see the infowindow with the content 'Found You!'? (BTW: the types are not correct, it has to be `['dentist','store','restaurant']`)

Comment: Alright, I fixed those. I saw them with the | separators on their documentation. I do see the 'Found You!' pop up. But the markers for the nearby places do not come up.

Comment: what's the location returned by `navigator.getCurrentPosition`?

Comment: It says "undefined" when I type navigator.getCurrentPosition in console

Comment: I mean the `pos` inside your code, which value does it have(which location will be used for the nearbySearch)?

Comment: Did you not disable geolocation in your browser?

Comment: @Dr.Molle it doesn't return that information to me for some reason. It should be LatLng coordinates, correct? Are you able to get coordinates? My geolocation is enabled as I do see the infowindow that says "Found You!" and its my correct location.

Comment: At http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/2qogdy7g/ you should see your coordinates inside the InfoWindow, what is it?

Comment: The location is: @(33.689052,-117.82815479999998) - I can see all the markers here. What did you do differently?

Comment: I also copied your code into my JS file and tried it. It updated the infowindow with my coordinates, but it didn't bring up the markers. So weird. I also tried on Firefox to make sure and cleared my cache/cookies. Your jsfiddle demo works perfectly fine though.

Comment: Ok I think I got it working, I had to change the variables for infowindow. I am pretty sure they were conflicting with each other (the "I found you!" infowindow and the places infowindows). I did use your initialize(); though. Didn't realize I could have just done that. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated coded that I got to work.. I made some customizations to the markers, but this works now. As mentioned in the comments, I believe the issue had to do with the variables set for infowindow. I changed the geolocation one to 'infowindowLocation' instead and adjusted in the error flags section.

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var service;

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    // Start Geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindowLocation = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Found You!'
            });

            var request = {
                location: pos,
                radius: 3218.69,
                types: ['dentist']
            };

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

            map.setCenter(pos);

        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

// Callback for Places
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Create Marker for Places
function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var image = 'img/flag.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        title: place.name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: image
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}

// Google Maps Error Flags

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindowLocation = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

initialize();
```